# MasterViewController's TableViewController null in constructor?

Tags: ios

I have the following MasterViewController:

```
- (id) init{
self = [super init];
if(self){
    //self.title = @"Main Menu";
    //self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);

    UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"view-1_0000s_0000_Muskoka-Logo1"]];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView;

    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.tableView.opaque = NO;
    self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage    imageNamed:@"view-1_0002s_0003s_0001_Bottom-panel"]];
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;

}
return self;

}
```

It crashes when I try to set the background colour of the tableviewcontroller because the tableview inside the master is null. The image there is not null of course.

My only guess is that [super init] is not working properly?

Comment: Because of `if (self)`, and the control flow reaches your code, then `self` cannot be `nil`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view controller's views and subviews do not exist until they have been loaded, which will occur during `loadView` (where the view hierarchy is built either in code or from a xib) All of those customisations should be in `viewDidLoad`. I'm surprised it's crashing, though, messages to nil don't cause crashes.

Comment: So the tableview should be initialized in the [super init].

Comment: No. If you're subclassing UITableViewController, the table view will be available to you in viewDidLoad.